# UrlFetchApp.fetch нет разрешения

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

пытаюсь создать триггер для гугл таблицы
создал скрипт :

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://trello.com/b/")
  Logger.log(res)
}
```

пытаюсь постучать куда угодно, но выходит ошибка:

```
Скрипт Google Apps: Вам не разрешено вызывать пользователя UrlFetchApp.fetch. Необходимые разрешения: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request.
```

добавил ее в манифест:

```
{
  "timeZone": "Europe/Moscow",
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "oauthScopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request"]
}
```

но ошибка такая же все ровно.

Что Я упустил? все что нахожу в интернете, это "просто добавьте разрешение"

Comment: Триггеры и так автоматические. Что вы имели ввиду?

Comment: @oshliaer удалил слово

Answer (score 1):

Функция onEdit не может отправлять запросы на внешние сайты, требующих авторизации: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#Installable

Можно переименовать функцию и сделать свой installable триггер, срабатывающий при редактировании, и привязать его к своей новой функции.

Обсуждение по этой теме: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56073360/google-sheets-scripts-function-urlfetchapp-fetch-does-not-run-from-onedite-bu

Answer (score 0):

С большой вероятностью, вы должны запустить `onEdit` для авторизации из редактора. В этом случае, другие пользователи все равно не будут иметь возможности отправить запрос, т.к. они тоже должны авторизовать приложение.

Других вариантов просто нет.

Comment: Я запускал скрипт из редактора, все работает, но при вызове из таблицы появляется ошибка

Comment: Сомнительно. Вы что-то скрываете или не доделываете. Приведите полный листинг.